# Python+Odbc: My query doesn't work when I put wildcards like '%'

Tags: python, sql, pyodbc

I tried to query using this code:

```sql
SELECT MES_User_ID, MES_User_Email_Address
FROM MES_User
WHERE MES_User_Email_Address LIKE 'excollege100%'
```

It returned nothing.
I expect it to return:
219730 excollegetest1006@gmail.com

Tried the following:

1.)

```sql
SELECT MES_User_ID, MES_User_Email_Address
FROM MES_User
WHERE MES_User_Email_Address LIKE 'excollegetest1%'
```

It returned what I expected but I want to narrow it down more by adding two zeros, so that the result will return 100X series.

2.)

```sql
SELECT MES_User_ID, MES_User_Email_Address
FROM MES_User
WHERE MES_User_Email_Address LIKE 'excollegetest1##%'
```

It returned nothing

```py
quser = r'excollegetest100%'

cursor = cnxn.cursor()
cursor.execute('''
SELECT MES_User_ID, MES_User_Email_Address
FROM MES_User
WHERE MES_User_Email_Address LIKE ?
''', quser)
row = cursor.fetchmany()

for row in cursor:
    print(str(row[0]) + " : " + row[1])
```

I doesn't return anything.

Comment: The first query shouldn't what you expect since the pattern `excollege100%` does not contain _"test"_ between _"excollege100"_ and _"100"._ The second one shouldn't return `excollegetest1006@gmail.com` either.

Comment: Thanks for noticing that @TedKleinBergman that was a typo. Sorry for that. It should be excollegetest100%

Comment: Can you able to retrieve data from database using that query? And on the point 2. you have placed # instead of 0?

Comment: @Sivaprasath when I used the "SQL Server Management Studio" every query above works fine. But using the pyodbc, it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```
quser = 'excollegetest100'

sql='SELECT MES_User_ID,MES_User_Email_Address FROM MES_User WHERE 
MES_User_Email_Address LIKE %s'

args=[quser+'%']
cursor.execute(sql,args)
row = cursor.fetchall()
```

Comment: Hi Arun,

Here is the output of your suggestion:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 15, in <module>
    cursor.execute(sql, args)
pyodbc.ProgrammingError: ('The SQL contains 0 parameter markers, but 1 parameters were supplied', 'HY000')

Comment: @vigilantes Try that recipe with the `sql` string ending in `LIKE ?` instead of `LIKE %s`. To my knowledge, `%s` is not a valid parameter marker in pyodbc, hence the DB engine complains about you passing in a parameter where none can be substituted.

Comment: @shmee I tried this

`quser = 'excollegetest100'

sql = '''SELECT MAS_User_ID,MAS_User_Email_Address FROM MAS_User 

WHERE MAS_User_Email_Address LIKE ?'''

args = [quser+'%']`

Comment: Can you try this 
`sql = 'SELECT "MES_User_ID","MES_User_Email_Address" FROM "MES_User" WHERE "MES_User_Email_Address" LIKE (' + "'%" + quser + "%'" + ')`

Comment: `cursor.execute(sql)

row = cursor.fetchall()
`

Answer (score 0):

```
import pyodbc

cnxn = pyodbc.connect("database")
cursor = cnxn.cursor()

qry = "excollege100"

sql = ('''SELECT MES_User_ID, MES_User_Email_Address 
    FROM MES_User 
    WHERE MES_User_Email_Address LIKE ?''')

param = f'{qry}%'
row = cursor.execute(sql, param)
row = cursor.fetchmany()

for row in cursor:
    try:
        print(str(row[0]) + " : " + row[1])
    except:
        print("TypeError")
        print (str(row))
```